# Menu item to view with wildcard

Tags: 7, views, routes

I created a view that dynamically displays some nodes depending a wildcard in the path.
The view path is something like /fruits/%
So /fruits/apples would show all the apple nodes, /fruits/oranges all the orange nodes and so on.

Works great when I directly go to a path like www.mysite/fruits/apples but I can't create a menu item with the path 'fruits/apples', I always get the message The path 'fruits/apples' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.
Also tried creating URL aliases for the path but same message.

/* Update */

I use this code to get the argument I need to load the right 'fruit', it returns false when no term_id is set, and that seems to be a problem. When return true, I can set the menu item but then the view will always try the display the page in stead of showing the 'No Results Behavior'

```
$term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name(arg(2), 'fruit_type');
$term_id = key($term);
if(isset($term_id)){
  $handler->argument = $term_id;
  return TRUE;
}

return FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse `fruits/apple` with `fruits/apples`. Drupal will not allow you to create menu entries for paths whose Views Contextual Filter argument does not validate.

Comment: I'm afraid that thats just a typo in my question. There both the same paths, I edited the question.

Comment: In that case, I do not know a solution. I can, however, confirm that it is usually possible to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thats at least reassuring, i'll have a look at the Contextual Filter, it's a custom php script, I guess something is wrong there.